# PHP Passing string with inner space

Tags: php, string

I have this code `$_SESSION['akey'] = $row['akey']` and the value in `$row['akey']` is

> eosUb w wc

**Note: Inner spaces between string**

But value passes to `$_SESSION['akey']` is only

> eosUb

EDIT: `click.php?refid=<?=$_SESSION['akey']` shows `click.php?refid=eosUb`

Comment: I guess your problem is with` \n` or something like that, check what gives you `var_dump($row['akey'])` and `var_dump( $_SESSION['akey'] )` after coping `$row['akey']` value there

Comment: This shows: string(10) "eosUb w wc"

Comment: so for both var_dumps you have same string(10) "eosUb w wc" yes ?

Comment: $_SESSION['akey'] try '".$_SESSION['akey']."'

Comment: which version of php you're using ?

Comment: @Mohamed PHP Version 5.3.10-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it :

```
click.php?refid=<?=urlencode($_SESSION['akey'])
```

EDIT: This should results: `click.php?refid=eosUb+w+wc`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have problem with new lines in your string during echo 
first make sure that `var_dump( $_SESSION['akey'] )` brings you "eosUb w wc"
then you can try to remove line breaks by

```
click.php?refid=<?= preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $_SESSION['akey'])); ?>
```